# AngularFire valueChanges with idField and non-existent document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

If I call `valueChanges` on a Firestore document that doesn't exist, it returns `undefined`:

```js
this.afs.doc('bad_document_ref').valueChanges().subscribe(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot) // undefined
});
```

But if I call `valueChanges` on the same bad ref, but I pass in the `idField` parameter, it returns an object with just the id:

```js
this.afs.doc('bad_document_ref').valueChanges({ idField: 'custom_doc_id' }).subscribe(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot) // { custom_doc_id: 'bad_document_ref' }
});
```

---

I would like for the two above examples to return the same thing. I can do this by adding a pipe:

```js
this.afs.doc('bad_document_ref').valueChanges({ idField: 'custom_doc_id' })
    .pipe(map(snapshot => {
        if(!snapshot) return undefined;
        if (Object.keys(snapshot).length === 1 && Object.keys(snapshot)[0] === 'custom_id_field') {
            return undefined;
        }
        return snapshot;
    }))
    .subscribe(snapshot => {

    console.log(snapshot) // undefined

});
```

Is there a reason why the first two examples don't return the same thing? It seems like the logical thing to do, for the sake of consistency. Maybe there is a reason I'm not thinking of for why they would return different values?

Answer (score 0):

The valueChange() method is basically the current state of your collection. You can listen for changes on the collection’s documents by calling valueChanges() on the collection reference. It returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the document data is included.

When  you pass an option object with an idField key containing a string like .valueChanges({ idField: 'propertyId' });  , it returns JSON objects with their document ID mapped to a property with the name provided by idField.

When the document doesn't actually exist, you would expect it to return nothing. In the first piece of code, you are not providing idField and the document doesn't exist, the observable returned undefined, which is justified. However, when you specify idField in the second piece of code, you basically say that when you return the data, you want the id of the document to be added to it. However if there is no data, there should not be any value returned, which is what you wanted to point out and which is quite justified. In other words, if the document does not exist, ideally it should return undefined even if you specify the idField parameter.

A [GitHub link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2753) pointing towards the same issue says that the appropriate behavior is addressed in version 7 api.

Another [GitHub link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/pull/2777https://) to be followed on this.

Comment: I understand how the idField parameter works and why when I include it, it adds the document id to the object. My question is aimed more towards intended functionality of the angularfire api. Wouldn't it make more sense for the observable to return undefined if the document doesn't exist?

Comment: Okay I got your point now and the question too. I was trying to provide a complete answer for the community, or whoever visits this question to know what these methods do, and how it works. Coming to your question, as you want a pointed answer, I will work on it and get back to you. Also was it you who downvoted my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am using:
`angularFirestore.collection<Item>('items');`

Note that for the object mapped I use `<Item>`, so maybe you can use it in your **doc**.